# Prove decomposition of elements in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that **every** element in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ can be written as a finite product of irreducible elements.

Comment: What do you know about the norm function
$$N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2?$$

Comment: I know that it is multiplicative. And that one can show with it that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has irreducible elements that are not prime.

Comment: Do you know how to identify the units of the ring using the norm?

Comment: Well, for $a, a' \in R$ a is a unit when $a*a' = 1$. Therefore, when $N(a*a') = N(1)$. But $N(1) = 1 = N(a)*N(a')$ because of multiplicity. In my textbook it is that because of the last equality it is $a = 1$ or $a = -1$. But why?

Comment: $a^2+5b^2=1$ and $a,b$ are integers, so you can deduce that $b=0$ and $a=\pm1$. Then you can proceed as in lhf's updated answer: Prove that $z=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ is decomposable into irreducibles by induction on $N(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Adapt the proof for $\mathbb Z$, comparing elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ using the norm function $N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=a^2+5b^2$.

The proof I have in mind is by induction and runs like this:

Take $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$. If $\alpha$ is irreducible, there is nothing to prove. Otherwise, $\alpha = \beta \gamma$, with $\beta, \gamma$ both not units. Then $N(\alpha)=N(\beta)N(\gamma) > N(\beta,)N(\gamma)$. By induction, $\beta, \gamma$ decompose into irreducibles, and so does $\alpha$.

The only detail is $N(\tau)=1$ iff $\tau$ is a unit.

Answer (score 0):

Because $-5\equiv 3\pmod 4$ the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is the ring of integers of the field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})$ and we have for each element $x=a+b\sqrt{-5}$ has a norm $N(x)=a^2+5b^2$. Therefore, because of the multiplicativity of the norm, $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ we can get the factorization of an element in irreducible elements.

But this decomposition in irreducible elements is not unique because $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not principal. For instance we have $$6=2\cdot3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$$ and we can prove that each of the four numbers is irreducible (*notice that the norms of $2,3,1+\sqrt{-5}$ and $1-\sqrt{-5}$ are $4,9,6$ and $6$ respectively*).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But why is it that the multiplicativity of the norm secures that we can get the factorization of an element in irreducible elements?

Comment: @Taufi Suppose by contradiction that there exists some element which is not a product of irreducibles. Pick such an element $a$ with minimum norm: clearly $a$ cannot be irreducible (otherwise $a$ would be a product of irreducibles), so that $a=bc$. Recalling that elements of norm $\pm 1$ are invertible and viceversa, you have $$N(a)=N(b)N(c)$$ so that $b,c$ have smaller norm than $a$. By minimality of $N(a)$, you have that $b,c$ are products of irreducibles, hence $a=bc$ is a product of irreducibles: a contradiction.

Comment: @Taufi: "We can get" is not "there exists". For example if $x=-2+4\sqrt{-5}$ you have $N(x)=84=2^2\cdot3\cdot7$ so $6$ divides $N(x)$ then "if you remember" that $6$ is the norm of $1+\sqrt{-5}$ you can replace the factor $6$ by $N(1+\sqrt{-5})$ and in fact you can verify that $1+\sqrt{-5}$ is a factor of $x$. Efective calculations in number fields are the most of times hard and when the factorization is not unique (as for $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$) it is harder than in the "rare" cases in which you have unique factorization.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, Crostul and Piquito. @Crostul: Thanks for your quick proof, now the matter is more clear! But to give this contradiction I first have to show that +1 and -1 are the only units of which follows that b and c must have smaller norm than a?